# Correctly implement hashcode for matrix java

Tags: java

I have a Java class containing a 2D int array. I want to implement the `hashCode()` method so that different objects can be compared using their attributes and not reference. This is what I tried:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<getMatrix().length; i++) {
        hash =+ Arrays.hashCode(getMatrix()[i]);
    }
    return hash;
}
```

I also tried using `deepHashCode()` but didn't work. My problem is that when the `get()` method of a `HashMap` object is used, even though both the object have the same matrix, the `get()` method does not work properly.

EDIT:

Implementation of equals method

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean sameBoard = false;
        if(o != null && o instanceof Node) {
            Node node = (Node) o;
            int[][] board1 = this.getMatrix();
            int[][] board2 = node.getMatrix();
            return Arrays.deepEquals(board1, board2);
        }
        return sameBoard;
    }
```

Comment: Did you also implement `equals`? If so, can you also post your implementation of it as an edit to your post?

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov i posted it

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. We must be able to copy and paste your code in our IDE, compile and run it. My guess is that you modify the matrix after you've stored it in the map.

Comment: Do you mean `+=`, rather than `=+`? As it stands, your hash will simply be the hash of the last... row?

Comment: Good catch @AndyTurner! That said, that should still work: it's just a weaker hashCode.

Comment: deepHashCode() should work. It looks like you are using the matrix as key of a HashMap. That would be a bit dangerous because you must not change the values in the matrix after inserting it in the HashMap. Otherwise the results are not predictable. HashMap cannot find the key, when the key has been updated.